# bash script pass multi-line

Tags: bash, elasticsearch

I have the following bash script, modified from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-many-indices to include a `script` section, but it fails to run.

```
#!/bin/bash
ES="http://localhost:9200"
DEST="elb-staging-2019.03"
INDEX="elb-staging-2019.03.12"
INDEXES=$(curl -HContent-Type:application/json -XGET $ES/_cat/indices | awk '{print $3}' | grep $INDEX )



for i in $INDEXES
do
    echo "Index $i"
    # get index document size
    SIZE=$(curl -HContent-Type:application/json -XGET $ES/$i/_search?track_total_hits=true  -d'{
        "size": 0
    }' | jq ".hits.total.value")
    curl -HContent-Type:application/json -XPOST $ES/_reindex?requests_per_second=115&wait_for_completion=true -d'{
        "source": {
            "index": "'$i'",
            "size": 500
        },
        "dest": {
            index": "'$DEST'"
        },
        "conflicts": "proceed",
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",   
            "source": "ctx._source.index = ctx._index;"
        }
    }'
done
```

but I get an error

```
./es.sh: line 35: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: The `&` is being interpreted by the shell. Quote it.

Comment: Since you are already using `jq`, use it to generate the JSON for the `-d` argument as well, rather than using string interpolation. `jq --argjson i "$i" --argjson d "$DEST" '{source: {index: $i, ...}, ...}`.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ identifies your bug, without any reason to get other humans involved. The specific warning it throws is [SC1132](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1132).